# Ubuntu 22.04.2 - loses internet randomly/

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp

So I have a machine running ubuntu server 22.04.2 with a wired network connection which seems to lose internet randomly.
Running a continuous ping from the machine to google.com skips big chunks in the icmp_seq and then successful for a few packets and then drops out again - Getting about 75% - 92% packet loss.

Running a constant ping from my laptop to the machine shows no gaps or failed packets. On the physical side, I've replaced the network cable, changed the port on the router, and restarted everything multiple times.

One software/OS side - I've changed from Static IP to DHCP (all my other devices are DHCP) and rebuilt the netplan yaml file. Tested disabling iPv6 (my network isn't IPv6 setup yet)
I've checked Journalctl to see if anything happens there and the closest I've seen is a once-off carrier-lost comment.

I'm not sure what else to do. Any suggestions would be appreciated

> Is there any packet loss when pinging google.com from your laptop itself?

A ping from any other device on my network to google doesn't drop any Packets.
Ps. I've tried other sites with the same experience just in case some one was wondering if google doesn't like me...

Comment: Ok - I found the problem - after re-installing the system everything started working so I went ahead and started adding all the other applications I use on this system and it broke again! slowly working backward, I found that Plex Media Server was somehow causing the problem... yay!

Comment: This is really interesting. I've been troubleshooting this issue for months. The only way I've found to fix it is with a fresh OS install. But now you mention Plex... I run a Plex server on this machine and just turned it off. I hope this works because it's been a royal pain.